# Counting different words in a sentence

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I would like to know a 'pretty way' of counting different expressions in a sentence
Let's say I want to know many politicians are mentioned in the same sentence.

`>>> import re
>>> countc=0
>>> reg01 = re.compile('Trump')
>>> reg02 = re.compile('Biden')
>>> frase = "Trump won the republican primaries"
>>> if re.match(reg01, frase):
...     countc+=1`

I'm doing something like above, and it works. But I need to do it in some cases where there are many words for me to deal, I would like a prettier way.

Comment: Use a for loop and sum up the individual counts

Comment: Put all the words in a single regexp, like `Trump|Biden|Obama`. Then use `re.findall()` and get the length of the results.

Comment: Please define *prettier* way first.

Comment: You have to explicitly define the rules, are you only looking for words? can the patterns overlap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of words you want to find. Create a for loop to find every word.

```
import re
frase = "Trump won the republican primaries"

words = ['Trump','word1','word2','word3','word4']
for x in words:
    reg01 = re.compile(x)
    if re.match(reg01, frase):
        print(f'{x} is there in the sentence')
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the best way but I would use lists. If you are not processing large dataset it should be good enough. You should also add more cleaning to the data since in real world scenario there might be something like "Trump." "Trump's " etc.

```
def check_for_word(sentens:str) -> dict:

     sentens = sentens.replace(".", "")
     sentens = sentens.replace(",", "")
     sentens = sentens.split(" ")
     trump_count = len([x for x in sentens if x.lower() == 'trump'])
     biden_count = len([x for x in sentens if x.lower() == 'biden'])

     return {'trump': trump_count, 'biden': biden_count}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `collections.Counter()` as the starting point.

Let's start with:

```py
import collections
import re

interesting_words = ["Trump", "Biden"]
phrase = "Trump won the republican primaries but not and Biden."
word_counts = collections.Counter(re.split(r"\W", phrase))
total = sum(word_counts.get(word) for word in interesting_words)
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

def count_politicians(sentence, politicians):
    counts = {politician: 0 for politician in politicians}
    for politician in politicians:
        counts[politician] = len(re.findall(politician, sentence))
    return counts

politicians = ['Trump', 'Biden', 'Obama', 'Clinton']  # Add more politicians as needed
sentence = "Trump won the republican primaries"

politician_counts = count_politicians(sentence, politicians)
print(politician_counts)
```

Output:

```
{'Trump': 1, 'Biden': 0, 'Obama': 0, 'Clinton': 0}
```